Unable to Save Firebase Notification Message to Hive on iOS in Flutter (Works on Android)
I'm developing a Flutter app that uses Firebase for push notifications and Hive for local storage. I want to save incoming messages from Firebase notifications into Hive. The setup works perfectly on Android and also works on iOS when the app is in the foreground or background. However, it fails to save messages when the iOS app is in a terminated state. I’m using a StorageService to handle saving messages and have created User and MessageLocal Hive adapters for serialization.
Here’s the code in main.dart where I initialize Firebase, Hive, and Firebase Messaging:


@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  AppLogger.printLog("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");

  try {
    FirebaseMessagingHelper.showNotification(message);
  } catch (e) {
    AppLogger.printLog('error showing notification :$e');
  }
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  await FirebaseMessagingHelper.initialize();
  await ScreenUtil.ensureScreenSize();
  await Hive.initFlutter();

  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(<DeviceOrientation>[
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown
  ]);
  await Preference.load();

  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true,
  );
  AppLogger.printLog(
      'User granted permission: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    FirebaseMessagingHelper.processMessage(message);
    AppLogger.printLog('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
    AppLogger.printLog('Message data: ${message.data}');
    UtilFunctions.showSnackBar(
        title: message.notification?.title ?? '',
        message: message.notification?.body ?? '',
        remoteMessage: message);

    if (message.notification != null) {
      AppLogger.printLog(
          'Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');
    }
  });

  try {
    Hive.registerAdapter(UserAdapter());
    Hive.registerAdapter(MessageLocalAdapter());
  } catch (e) {
    AppLogger.printLog('Error registering adapters: $e');
  }

  const String environment =
      String.fromEnvironment('ENVIRONMENT', defaultValue: "PROD");
  Environment.instance().initConfig(environment);
  Global.host = Environment.instance().config.host;

  WakelockPlus.enable();

  await initServices();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

Future<void> initServices() async {
  await Get.putAsync<StorageService>(() => StorageService().init(),
      permanent: true);
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: const Size(360, 640),
      splitScreenMode: true,
      minTextAdapt: true,
      builder: (c, child) {
        return GetMaterialApp(
          title: 'AlignMates',
          onInit: () {
            Get.put(GlobalController(), permanent: true);
            Get.put(InternetConnectionCheckerController(), permanent: true);
          },
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(),
          themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
          darkTheme: AppThemeData.darkTheme,
          onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
            // Handle deep link routing here
            if (settings.name != null) {
              if (Routes.allRoutes.contains(settings.name)) {
                var page = Routes.pages
                    .firstWhereOrNull((e) => e.name == settings.name);
                return GetPageRoute(
                  page: page?.page,
                  binding: page?.binding,
                  settings: settings,
                );
              }
            }
            return null;
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

In FirebaseMessagingHelper, I process and save messages:

class FirebaseMessagingHelper {
  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static Future<void> initialize() async {
    // Initialize notification settings
    await _initializeNotifications();

    // Request permission
    await _requestPermission();

    // Set up foreground handler
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(_handleForegroundMessage);

    // Set up background/terminated handler
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then(_handleInitialMessage);
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(_handleMessageOpenedApp);
  }

  static Future<void> _initializeNotifications() async {
    var android = const AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
    var ios = const DarwinInitializationSettings(
      requestSoundPermission: true,
      requestBadgePermission: true,
      requestAlertPermission: true,
    );

    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      InitializationSettings(android: android, iOS: ios),
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: _handleNotificationResponse,
    );
  }

  static Future<void> _requestPermission() async {
    NotificationSettings settings =
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
      provisional: false,
    );
    print('User granted permission: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');
  }

  static Future<void> _handleForegroundMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
    print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
    await processMessage(message);
    await showNotification(message);
  }

  static Future<void> _handleInitialMessage(RemoteMessage? message) async {
    if (message != null) {
      print('Handling a message that opened the app from terminated state');
      await processMessage(message);
    }
  }

  static Future<void> _handleMessageOpenedApp(RemoteMessage message) async {
    print('Handling a message that opened the app from background state');
    await processMessage(message);
    handleNotificationTap(message);
  }

  static void _handleNotificationResponse(NotificationResponse response) {
    // Handle notification tap
    if (response.payload != null) {
      // Process the payload and navigate accordingly
      print('Notification payload: ${response.payload}');
    }
  }

  static Future<void> processMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
    // Handle your message data here
    if (message.data['type'] == 'message') {
      await handleMessageTypeNotification(message);
    }
    // Add other message type handlers as needed
  }

  static Future<void> handleMessageTypeNotification(
      RemoteMessage message) async {
    // Your existing message handling logic
    if (Get.isRegistered<StorageService>()) {
      var m = MessageResponse.fromJson(message.data);
      await Get.find<StorageService>()
          .saveMessage(MessageLocal.fromMessageResponse(m));
    } else {
      // Initialize storage service and save message
      await initializeStorageAndSaveMessage(message);
    }
  }

  static Future<void> initializeStorageAndSaveMessage(
      RemoteMessage message) async {
    final appDocumentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    Hive.init(appDocumentDirectory.path);
    await Hive.initFlutter();

    try {
      Hive.registerAdapter(UserAdapter());
      Hive.registerAdapter(MessageLocalAdapter());
    } catch (e) {
      print("Failed to initialize hive: $e");
    }

    var storageService = StorageService();
    await storageService.init();

    var m = MessageResponse.fromJson(message.data);
    await storageService.saveMessage(MessageLocal.fromMessageResponse(m));
    await storageService.closeMessageBox();
  }

  static Future<void> showNotification(RemoteMessage payload) async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'default_notification_channel_id',
      'Notification',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      ticker: 'ticker',
      icon: "app_icon",
      playSound: true,
    );

    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidDetails);

    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      payload.notification?.title ?? payload.data['gcm_title'],
      payload.notification?.body ?? payload.data['gcm_alert'],
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: payload.data.toString(),
    );
  }

  static Future<String?> getToken() async {
    try {
      String? fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();

      if (fcmToken != null) {
        return fcmToken;
      } else {
        // Attempt to retrieve APNs token if FCM token is not available
        final apnsToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getAPNSToken();
        if (apnsToken != null) {
          // Convert APNs token to FCM token if needed or handle accordingly
          return apnsToken; // or some custom handling
        } else {
          AppLogger.printLog('APNS token is not available');
          return null;
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      AppLogger.printLog('Error getting FCM token: $e');
      return null; // or return a default value
    }
  }

  static void handleNotificationTap(RemoteMessage message) {
    var data = NotificationCreateRequest.fromJson(message.data);
    if (data.type == NotificationType.appUpdate) {
      UtilFunctions.openAppInStore();
    } else if (data.type == NotificationType.friendRequest) {
      Get.toNamed(Routes.friendRequestsRoute);
    } else if (data.type == NotificationType.friendRequestAccepted) {
      Get.toNamed(Routes.friendsRoute);
    } else if (data.type == NotificationType.message) {
      if (data.senderName != null &&
          data.senderImagePath != null &&
          data.conversationId != null) {
        Get.put(ChatController());

        Get.find<ChatController>().openChat(
            u: UserDetail(
              name: data.senderName,
              id: data.actorId,
              imagePath: data.senderImagePath,
            ),
            conversationId: data.conversationId!);
      }
    } else if (data.postShortId != null) {
      Get.to(() => const FeedOpenView(),
          arguments: {'shortId': data.postShortId}, binding: BindingsBuilder(
        () {
          var currentTag = UtilFunctions.getRandomChars(10);
          Get.put(FeedOpenController(tag: currentTag), tag: currentTag);
        },
      ));
    }
  }
}

I use Storage service to save and get messages
import 'package:alignmates/utils/constants.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

import '../../helper/hive.helper.dart';
import '../../hive/user.model.dart';
import '../../modules/feed/controller/feed.controller.dart';
import '../../modules/home/controller/home.controller.dart';
import '../../modules/profile/controller/profile.controller.dart';

class StorageService extends GetxService {
  Box<User>? userBox;
  Box? generalUseBox;
  User? user;
  Box<List<dynamic>>? messageBox;

  Future<StorageService> init() async {
    userBox = await Hive.openBox<User>(Constants.userBox);

    generalUseBox = await Hive.openBox(Constants.generalBox);

    messageBox = await Hive.openBox<List<dynamic>>(Constants.messagesBox);

    user = userBox?.get(Constants.userData);

    return this;
  }

  Future<void> closeMessageBox() async {
    if (messageBox?.isOpen == true) {
      await messageBox?.close();
      messageBox = null; // Optional: set to null to avoid unintended access
    }
  }

  // Save a message to the Hive box
  Future<void> saveMessage(MessageLocal message) async {
    // Check if the conversation already exists
    List<dynamic>? messages = messageBox?.get(message.conversationId);

    if (messages != null) {
      // If it exists, append the new message
      if (messages.firstWhereOrNull((m) => m.id == message.id) == null) {
        messages.add(message);
      }
    } else {
      // If it doesn't exist, create a new list with the message
      messages = [message];
    }

    // Save the updated list back to the box
    await messageBox?.put(message.conversationId, messages);
  }

  // Retrieve messages by conversation ID
  List<MessageLocal> getMessagesByConversationId(String conversationId) {
    final messages =
        messageBox?.get(conversationId)?.cast<MessageLocal>() ?? [];
    messages.sort((a, b) => a.createdAt!.compareTo(b.createdAt!));

    return messages.reversed.toList();
  }

  Future<void> createProfile(User u) async {
    await userBox?.put(Constants.userData, u);
    user = u;
  }

  Future<void> saveProfile({required User user}) async {
    this.user = user;

    await HiveHelper.updateUser(key: Constants.userData, user: user);

    Get.find<ProfileController>().update();

    Get.find<HomeController>().update();

    Get.find<FeedController>().update();
  }

  Future<void> deleteAll() async {
    await userBox?.clear();
    await generalUseBox?.deleteFromDisk();
  }
}

Problem
Despite this setup, I’m unable to save messages from Firebase notifications into Hive on iOS when the app is in a terminated state. Everything works fine on Android, and on iOS when the app is in the foreground or background. However, as soon as the app is terminated on iOS, incoming notifications do not get stored in Hive.
Question
Is there a way to reliably save Firebase notifications to Hive on iOS while the app is in a terminated state? Are there specific configurations or workarounds for handling notifications on iOS in this scenario?
Additional Information
I’m using GetX for dependency injection.
Notifications display correctly using FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin when the app is in the foreground.
The issue is iOS-specific and does not occur on Android.
Thank you for any suggestions on handling Firebase notifications and storing messages in Hive when the app is terminated on iOS!

restate your question and make it as short and concise as possible, provide logs or errors if any.
